# React - Jest - Enzyme: How to mock ref properties

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing test for a component with ref. I'd like to mock the ref element and change some properties but have no idea how to. Any suggestions?

```
// MyComp.jsx
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRef = this.getRef.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({elmHeight: this.elm.offsetHeight});
  }
  getRef(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <span ref={getRef}>
        Stuff inside 
      </span>
    </div>
  }
}

// MyComp.test.jsx
const comp = mount(<MyComp />);
// Since it is not in browser, offsetHeight is 0
// mock ref offsetHeight to be 100 here... How to?
expect(comp.state('elmHeight')).toEqual(100);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So here's the solution, according to discussion in
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1937

It is possible to monkey-patch the class with a non-arrow function, where "this" keyword is passed to the right scope.

```
function mockGetRef(ref:any) {
  this.contentRef = {offsetHeight: 100}
}
jest.spyOn(MyComp.prototype, 'getRef').mockImplementationOnce(mockGetRef);
const comp = mount(<MyComp />);
expect(comp.state('contentHeight')).toEqual(100);
```

Comment: Tried using this and got
` Cannot spy the getRef property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: How do you mock on function component?

Comment: @vnxyz you were probably using an arrow function, you'd need `ref={this.getRef}` in your component

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the ref by using `Object.defineProperty`. For example:

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'offsetHeight', {
   value: 100,
   writable: true,
   configurable: true
});
```