# How to mock ref object in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that one of its props is a ref to another element. Dom structure looks like this:

```
<div ref={tagRef}>text</div>
<Component tagRef={tagRef}/>
```

How can I mock the tagRef?

```
render(<Component tagRef={tagRef}/>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Jest - Enzyme: How to mock ref properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721999/react-jest-enzyme-how-to-mock-ref-properties)

Comment: what do you mean? if you want to check ref's method is called(e.g. `tagRef.current.focus`) you may mock that child component with object you may spy for it's methods